# Polling status of Google Speech to Text

Tags: google-apis-explorer

It appears that I have correctly connected the system to the audio recording (.flac). It sent me back the ok 200 code and the name:ID # however I am trying to check the status. I am using the Google API for hits. Can you help me out? The gcloud ml speech operations describe with my ID number isnt working.